# Does the hyperref breaklinks option have any effect?

Tags: hyperref, urls

According to the [hyperref](https://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) documentation, `breaklinks` 'is intended for internal use' and 'automatically set according to the driver features' – which, however, doesn't tell us whether it's automatically turned on or off. There are multiple examples of it being recommended on StackExchange and elsewhere: it seems these are mostly looking for better URL breaking, as the [xurl](https://ctan.org/pkg/xurl) package provides. Is there any reason to enable it manually?

I have tried the following MWE in pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, and LuaLaTeX, and cannot find any differences with or without the option enabled:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
% \hypersetup{breaklinks=true} % set automatically by hyperref?
% \usepackage{xurl} % uncomment for correct output
\urlstyle{same}

\begin{document}

\url{https://ctan.org/jshdlfkjshlkdjfhsalkdfjcnlskjfnhlsdkjfnclskjfchsalkjcfalnskdjcfhdklnsjcfhlnsdkjfcalnskfjlnskfjhnslkjdfadklnsjfchdlnskjfchlnskjfhdlnskfjchsaldknfjchdslcfknjashlkcfjnslafnksjdhcfaklnsjcfhlsadknjcfh}

\url{https://ctan.org/jshdlfkjs/hlkdjfhsalkdfjcnlskjfnhlsdkjfnclskjfc/hsalkjcf-alnskdjcfhdklns/jcfhlnsdkjfcalnskfjlnskfjhnslkjdfad/klnsjfchdlnsk-jfchlnskj/fhdlnskfjchsaldknfjchdslcfknjashlkc-fjnslafnksjdhcfaklnsj/cfhlsadknjcfh}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Imho the boolean is used only with dvips.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Compiling an url to DVI: the `dvips` driver (used when one prefers the `LATEX`→`DVI`→`PostScript`→`PDF`), because of internal reasons, can’t issue line breaks in the middle of a link.  That was the reason there is package `breakurl` allowing breaking urls in DVI documents.

Package `hyperref` offers package option `breaklinks`. In the documentation, chapter 3.3 you can read:

[image]

In other words, `hyperref` sets `breaklinks` only to `true` if an DVI is build.

Allowing line breaks in urls compiling to pdf is supported by package `url`. Package `xurl` is an expanded version of `url`, which allows line breaking at every point in the url. BTW: call package `xurl` before `hyperref`, as I showed in the following corrected MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xurl} % uncomment for correct output
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{breaklinks=true} % set automatically by hyperref?

\urlstyle{same}


\begin{document}

\url{https://ctan.org/jshdlfkjshlkdjfhsalkdfjcnlskjfnhlsdkjfnclskjfchsalkjcfalnskdjcfhdklnsjcfhlnsdkjfcalnskfjlnskfjhnslkjdfadklnsjfchdlnskjfchlnskjfhdlnskfjchsaldknfjchdslcfknjashlkcfjnslafnksjdhcfaklnsjcfhlsadknjcfh}

\url{https://ctan.org/jshdlfkjs/hlkdjfhsalkdfjcnlskjfnhlsdkjfnclskjfc/hsalkjcf-alnskdjcfhdklns/jcfhlnsdkjfcalnskfjlnskfjhnslkjdfad/klnsjfchdlnsk-jfchlnskj/fhdlnskfjchsaldknfjchdslcfknjashlkc-fjnslafnksjdhcfaklnsj/cfhlsadknjcfh}

\end{document}
```

Compiled with `pdflatex` the boolean `breaklinks` is set by `hyperref` to `false` and results in

[image]

Compiled with `pdftex` the boolean `breaklinks` results to `true` and we get the dvi file:

[image]

As you can see on my system the url has no breaks. Because I do not use DVI I did not investigate the reason for this non-breaking.

Comment: Thank you very much – so the option has an effect when using DVI, but not with pdflatex/xelatex/lualatex.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does.

You will need to use this:

```
\usepackage[breaklinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{breakurl}
```

Now, you'll just need to add this code:

```
    \expandafter\def\expandafter\UrlBreaks\expandafter{\UrlBreaks%  save the current one
    \do\a\do\b\do\c\do\d\do\e\do\f\do\g\do\h\do\i\do\j%
    \do\k\do\l\do\m\do\n\do\o\do\p\do\q\do\r\do\s\do\t%
    \do\u\do\v\do\w\do\x\do\y\do\z\do\A\do\B\do\C\do\D%
    \do\E\do\F\do\G\do\H\do\I\do\J\do\K\do\L\do\M\do\N%
    \do\O\do\P\do\Q\do\R\do\S\do\T\do\U\do\V\do\W\do\X%
    \do\Y\do\Z\do\/\do-}
```

Comment: Using that with my MWE, I can't find any difference in the resulting PDF, whether I have `\usepackage[breaklinks]{hyperref}` or `\usepackage{hyperref}`.

Comment: It should work now

Comment: That's a nice alternative to the xurl package; thank you! Still, however, it works whether or not I have the `breaklinks` option enabled.